# Apache (Unix) List Directory - Download

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, mac

There is a website which is hosted on Apache which Lists a directory of files and folders, i want to download all the files and folders of that site what software is required to do this?

i.e.  http://www.siteaddress.com/files

This lists a load of files and folders and I which to download the lot to my pc.

Answer (score 2):

Use `wget`.

Example:

```
$ wget -r http://your_url.com/list.php
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to say, I am doing this from a windows pc (or mac)

Comment: You have `wget` on Windows **AND** Mac OS. You don't have it out of the box, but you definitely could install it.

Comment: @MartGriff `wget` is available for windows and mac. To not forget to read `wget` help especially about excluding domains and directories and recursion level, otherwise you are going to download many-many unnecessary files :)

Comment: @MartGriff, http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: @MartGriff: besides, you should not tag your question with **UNIX** if you want Windows specific answers. Or maybe explicitly state that you are looking for a Windows or Mac OS X solution...